# PYTHON: Accessing elements of a list of lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have to go through each pronunciation of a word, which I've stored as such: each word is in a dictionary (below called wordAndPron), and each word in that dictionary has several pronunciations stored as lists.

```
{ 'RECORD' : 

[ ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D'], 

['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D'], 

['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']]

}

{ 'MORTGAGE' :

[ ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH'],

['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']]

}
```

How do I access the elements of each list? So what position would each of the phonemes, like 'R' and 'AH0', be?

I'm going to be using a for loop to go through and compare phonemes to one another (finding rhyming words), but I'm unsure how to do so.

```
def primary_stress_position(wordAndPron):
        stress = ''
        stressedPosition = 0
        phoneme = 0
        for phoneme in wordAndPron.values():   # <<< Problem area
                if phoneme.endswith('1'):
                        stress = phoneme
                        stressedPosition = position
                position += 1
        return stress, stressedPosition
```

I apologize if this is a very obvious/simple question, but I'm just starting Python from Java and have only taken one other programming class!

This is classwork. I'm not asking how to write the entire program, only how to access the individual elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the one and only value of the `wordAndPron` dict is a list of lists, you can use a nested `for` loop to access the phonemes within. And since you have several pronunciations per word, instead of returning just the stressed phoneme of the first pronunciation in the list, you should make the function `yield` the finding so that the caller can obtain all the pronunciations of a given word from the generator:

```
def primary_stress_position(wordAndPron):
    for entry in wordAndPron.values()[0]:
        for pron in entry:
            stress = ''
            stressedPosition = None
            position = 0
            for phoneme in pron:
                if phoneme.endswith('1'):
                    stress = phoneme
                    stressedPosition = position
                    break
                position += 1
            yield stress, stressedPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the words in one dictionary.  Access values and parts of values as follows.

```
>>> d = {
'RECORD' :
[ ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D'],
['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D'],
['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']],
'MORTGAGE' :
[ ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH'],
['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']]
}
>>> d['RECORD']
[['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D'], ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D'], ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']]
>>> d['RECORD'][0]
['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
>>> d['RECORD'][0][0]
'R'
>>>
```

It is not clear to me what you are trying to do in your function, so I cannot say how to revise it.

Answer (score 0):

to access elements of a list of lists in a dictionary you just need to use **three for loops**, it's fairly simple, this code is self-explanatory:

```
d = { 'RECORD' : 

[ ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D'], 

['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D'], 

['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']]

, 
 'MORTGAGE' :

[ ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH'],

['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']]

}


for outter_list in d.values():
    print(f'the outter_list now is: {outter_list} \n')
    for inner_list in outter_list:
        print(f'the inner_list now is: {inner_list}')
        for element in inner_list:
            print(f'element: {element}  from current innerlist: {inner_list}')
        print('\n')
    print('--------------------------------------------')
```

Output:

```
the outter_list now is: [['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D'], ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D'], ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']]

the inner_list now is: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: AH0  from current innerlist: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: K  from current innerlist: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: AO1  from current innerlist: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: D  from current innerlist: ['R', 'AH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']


the inner_list now is: ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D']
element: EH1  from current innerlist: ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D']
element: K  from current innerlist: ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D']
element: ER0  from current innerlist: ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D']
element: D  from current innerlist: ['R', 'EH1', 'K', 'ER0', 'D']


the inner_list now is: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: IH0  from current innerlist: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: K  from current innerlist: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: AO1  from current innerlist: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']
element: D  from current innerlist: ['R', 'IH0', 'K', 'AO1', 'R', 'D']


--------------------------------------------
the outter_list now is: [['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH'], ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']]

the inner_list now is: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']
element: M  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']
element: AO1  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']
element: G  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']
element: AH0  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']
element: JH  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'AH0', 'JH']


the inner_list now is: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']
element: M  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']
element: AO1  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']
element: R  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']
element: G  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']
element: IH0  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']
element: JH  from current innerlist: ['M', 'AO1', 'R', 'G', 'IH0', 'JH']


--------------------------------------------
```